# Organizer - Archives. Different name than ${PRODUCT_NAME}

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm having an issue that's driving me crazy. I'm using Ejecta a JS wrapper (sorta like Phone Gap but for games).

I double checked everything in xcode and ${PRODUCT_NAME} is set correctly in 
"Build Settings"->"Product Name", 
I check everywhere my knowledge took me and in Xcode there is no mention anywhere of "Ejecta".
And even if this is the case I archive (no issues, no warnings) and in Organizer, under name I find "Ejecta" instead of my correctly set App name.

Can someone help me understand why? Where the issue could be?

Thank you very much for any help

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinkig of a few things here.

1. The Bundle display name in your Info.plist file
2. Maybe you created a file called InfoPlist.strings with a CFBundleDisplayName 'Ejecta'

If this is none of it, I would do this to track it down (see included screenshot).

1. Create a Run Script phase in your target
2. Make sure the option 'Show Environment variables in build log' is selected
3. Make it stop with an error code (>0)
4. When the error is generated, right click -> show in log
5. Check everywhere for the word 'Electra'

[image]

Hope this helps

Comment: Tried but couldn't find anything. I also noticed that "Ejecta" is the name you see before the devices near the RUN/STOP buttons. I'm really lost :-(

Comment: i know this might sound stupid but have you tried, removing your application completely and launch it back on your device/simulator ?